# CMD+C doesn't kill the process

Tags: shell, kubernetes, kubectl

I frequently do port-forward on my mac but when I hit the CMD + C on my terminal to quit the port-forward, the process didn't get killed. i have to kill it in order to do a new port-forward. Do you know how to solve this issue on mac?

```
[2]  + 43679 suspended  kubectl port-forward pod/pod-0 27017:27017
```

Re-try

```
kubectl port-forward pod/pod-2 27017:27017
Unable to listen on port 27017: Listeners failed to create with the following errors: [unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:27017: bind: address already in use unable to create listener: Error listen tcp6 [::1]:27017: bind: address already in use]
error: unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{27017 27017}]
➜  ~ kill -9 43679
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac, the command you want is `CTRL+C` to quit/kill the process. The port forwarding is only in effect when the kubectl process is up.